# How I can fix the position of pie chart using achart engine in android

Tags: java, android, achartengine

In my application I want to fix the position of piechart at the centre,currently the pie chart has moved over the screen,when I touch it.I've used the achart engine for displaying the graph.What is the possible solution for it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try switching off zoom and panning.

```
    mRenderer.setZoomEnabled(false, false);
    mRenderer.setPanEnabled(false, false);
```